# Color/highlight or Add an icon to a specific file under project files

Tags: phpstorm

I have a very important file at the level of my project which is called `veiw.yml`. I would like to color/highlight or put an icon on it, in order to make it more attrective for me. In other words I want color or add an icon on one of my **yml** file at the level of my project files, that match the exactly regex expression `^views.yml$`.
Is there any way I could do the trick with phpstorm or change the phpstorm    [Atom Material Icons](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10044-atom-material-icons)  plugin configuration to add another icon to his iconslist?

Any idea, help would be appreciated.

[image: The view.yml is selected with the cursor]

Answer (score 3):

There are many options that can be used based on what exactly you want to achieve (why you need to highlight such file -- maybe you do not need highlighting but want something else and you do not know about such possibility):

1. Just add the desired file(s) or folder(s) to the [Favorites](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/managing-your-project-favorites.html) and use it instead of locating that file in a Project tree all the time.

   NOTE: Bookmarks have now replaced Favorites that existed in earlier versions of the IDE.
2. You can bookmark specific file with **Mnemonic Bookmark** (0..9 mainly) and then open such a file with just one key press from anywhere. This will also add a special mark next to the file name.

   NOTE: this is a per file thingy, no patterns.

   - https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/bookmarks.html#add-mnemonic-line-bookmark
   - https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/bookmarks.html#navigate-bookmarks
3. **If it has to be a different color in the Project view panel...** then just define custom scope at `Settings/Preferences | Appearance & Behavior | Scopes` and then (once scope is fully saved) associate that scope with specific color at `Settings/Preferences | Appearance & Behavior | File Colors` (ensure that appropriate checkbox is selected, which is by default).

   You will now have different backgrounds under such files in the Project View panel and other lists where file names are used.

   - https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/configuring-scopes-and-file-colors.html
   - https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/settings-file-colors.html
4. **ProjectTree Color Highlighter plugin** (https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/13951-projecttree-color-highlighter) -- allows assigning custom colors to custom files.

   NOTE: does not support patterns, only manually assigning files. Therefore this can be treated as a Plus or as a Minus, depending on your needs.
5. **Extra Icons plugin** (https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/11058-extra-icons). It allows assigning custom file icons based on folder or file name patterns. You can even bring your own icons.

   NOTE: From the 2022.1 version it is a paid plugin now (only $5 USD per year but still).